# CSS for different device sizes

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a simple page that consists of a form. There is a string for what the input box should be, and then the input box.

I want two different behaviors. When a cell phone is accessing the page, I want everything to be stacked on top of each other, but when the page is accessed via a computer I want multiple rows consisting of the the title, followed by the input box on the same row.

I've researched media queries by I still don't understand it enough to get through.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>

            <center>
            <div class="left">
                First name:
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                Last name:
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" name="lastname"/>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                Email Address:
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                Address:
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" name="address"/>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                I've practiced yoga for at least one year:
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="checkbox" name="oneyear"/>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
            </div>

            </center>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to make this work?

Comment: The only place I would think to start is use the @media screen and (max-width: 699px){
    
} 
But I don't know what I would put in there. I understand that this CSS would be applied if the screen met this requirement, but I don't know how to make certain divs suddenly go from inline to not inline.

Comment: Web development is always at its easiest when you develop for mobile devices first, then work your way up by using `min-width`. Going the other way around with `max-width` is a huge chore.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple choice: using Bootstrap to easily display your grid in different ways on window resize.
You can also use media queries, combine with a grid layout like Flexbox or Grid.
Or even use Jquery and the windworesize function.
Personnaly, i would choose Flexbox and the flex-direction propriety when the window reach the size of a smartphone or tablet.
To write a media querie, you just have to type something like @media screen and (max-width: 640px) for instance and write your rules inside the curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 22px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

        .clearfix::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        .my-form {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 920px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            padding: 20px;
        }

        .my-form .input {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px;
        }

        .my-form .input .left {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            line-height: 24px;
            padding: 3px 0;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .my-form .input .right {
            width: 100%;
        }

        .my-form .input input[type='text'], .my-form .input input[type='email'], .my-form .input textarea {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 30px;
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 3px;
            line-height: 22px;
            border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        }

        .my-form .input textarea {
            height: auto;
            min-height: 60px;
            resize: vertical;
        }

        .my-form .input input[type='submit'] {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: navy;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 22px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .my-form .input:after {
                content: "";
                clear: both;
                display: table;
            }
            .my-form .input .left {
                float: left;
                width: 35%;
                padding-right: 10px;
                margin-bottom: 0;
            }
            .my-form .input .right {
                float: right;
                width: 65%;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form class="my-form">
        <div class="input">
            <label class="left" for="firstname">
                First name:
            </label>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label class="left" for="lastname">
                Last name:
            </label>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label class="left" for="email">
                Email Address:
            </label>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label class="left" for="address">
                Address:
            </label>
            <div class="right">
                <textarea cols="10" rows="5" id="address" name="address"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="right">
                <label for="oneyear"><input type="checkbox" id="oneyear" name="oneyear" /> I've practiced yoga for at least one year:</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need Media Query for this. Media query is basically writing different CSS for devices with different widths. You can learn more from here- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp

Also check out this article- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

You can also use jQuery for the same using matchmedia..
Here is a JSbin example for you- https://jsbin.com/kutacuzece/edit

```
(function($) {



    /*
        * We need to turn it into a function.
        * To apply the changes both on document ready and when we resize the browser.
        */

        function mediaSize() { 
            /* Set the matchMedia */
            if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 768px)').matches) {
            /* Changes when we reach the min-width  */
                $('body').css('background', '#222');
                $('strong').css('color', 'tomato');

            } else {
            /* Reset for CSS changes – Still need a better way to do this! */
                $('body, strong').removeAttr('style');
            }
        };

        /* Call the function */
      mediaSize();
      /* Attach the function to the resize event listener */
        window.addEventListener('resize', mediaSize, false);  

    })(jQuery);
```

OR you can use something as simple as this-

```
if ($(window).width() < 960) {
   $(selector).css({property:value, property:value, ...})
}
else if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(selector).css({property:value, property:value, ...})
}
else {
     $(selector).css({property:value, property:value, ...})
}
```

Comment: OP says to have researched media queries so your answer is not very useful. Perhaps you can give an example of how the problem can be solved.

Comment: @putvande can you please remove the negative vote as I have provided multiple solutions for the OP's queries... Thanks