# How to set a different grid size for device?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(420px, 0fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
  align-items: stretch;
}

.grid>article {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  background: #fafafa;
}

.grid>article img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.text {
  padding: 0 20px 20px;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<main class="grid">
  <article>
    <img class="grid" width="420px" src="image.jpg" />
    
    </a>
    
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Automating code assignment
      
      </a>
      
      </h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img class="grid" width="420px" src="image2.jpg" />
    
    </a>
    
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Automating code assignment 2
      
      </a>
      
      </h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <img class="grid" width="420px" src="image3.jpg" />
    
    </a>
    
    <div class="text">
      <h3>Automating code assignment 3
      
      </a>
      
      </h3>
      <p></p>
    </div>
  </article>
</main>
```

So the appropriate size for computer is `420px`, however, I would like to adjust it for devices, as this size is too big for a device.

Thank you :)

Comment: check @media rules https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Sidenote: `minmax(420px, 0fr)` doesn't make any sense, it is identical to `420px`.

Comment: @connexo more specifically the `0fr` makes no sense

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please do a litle research before asking here. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044016/css-for-different-device-sizes

Comment: Also as stated by @zerbene take a look on w3schools.com it has documentation and examples for most cases you will need when using css.

Answer (score 0):

Use css media queries for this. For example below section of code will only apply to screens with width less than 576px:

```
@media (max-width: 576px) {
 .text {
   padding: 0 20px 20px;
   color: black;
 }
}
```

Similarly below section of code will be applied to all screens with width greater than 576px.

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
 .text {
   padding: 0 20px 20px;
   color: black;
 }
}
```